# Buscar horário no mysql

Tags: mysql

Colegas,

Tenho um sistema do qual está armazenando o horário de cadastro dos usuários no seguinte formato no banco de dados Mysql:

> 11:11:00 ( o horário pode ser outro qualquer conforme o cadastro do usuário )

Porém criei uma tarefa Cron onde a cada minuto faça uma verificação no banco de dados  e execute uma tarefa baseado no horário de cadastro do usuário. Usei o seguinte código para verificação:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Data, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() AND Hora =  TIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

O problema é que se o horário do código acima passar o horário de cadastro, ele não executa a tarefa.Ex.:

Horário de cadastro for 11:11:00 e o horário do código for 11:11:01, não executa a tarefa.

Comment: você tem uma coluna para data e outra para hora ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar o `TIME_FORMAT`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Data, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() AND TIME_FORMAT(Hora,'%h:%i') =  TIME_FORMAT(TIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'%h:%i');
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/time_format.php